# Changing default T4 template for new EDMX files

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, t4, edmx, edmx-designer

How do I force VS to choose a custom template when creating EF models?

Details:

I built a custom template for generating EF entity classes from models. The solution has many projects with their own models and it is likely more will be added over time.

In order to prevent bugs in the future, I'd like to force VS to choose my template by default when creating EF models in the future. I'd prefer this to be at the Solution level, so that the change is part of the repository.

I have the template exported as a VS Item Template that is basically a clone of the default `EF 6.x DbContextGenerator` with the appropriate values replaced. I'm able to run it manually by using the "Add Code Generation Item..." option on the model designer view.

Comment: It's not clear here what your actual question is.

Comment: My bad @AdrianMole, I have a propensity to waffle. Edited.

Comment: Can't you just replace the original file with yours in the VS folder containing the .tt files?

Comment: @TimMaes, I'd like to avoid this. This change needs to be pushed to a team, so I'd prefer this to be self contained. If nothing else comes up, that's what we'll do.

Comment: Does everyone have the same setup? Can you have the template refer to a set file path outside the solution for everyone?